# Rejected from Facebook app reviewer "Please refer to the permission decision"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api, facebook-app-requests

I got this message from app reviewer "Please refer to the permission decision." and i couldn't understand what it is.

This is our [screencast](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RuoH6f4bDZqGII2CfTajknQqUgpQF25m) , we're using ads_management permission to reach ad posts created by ads manager.

This requires  manage_pages and ads_management permission actually but we already have manage_pages permission.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ads_posts/

Comment: I've got the same Facebook review response. With a screenshot of the permissions being asked after Facebook Login, which is as expected so I'm curious if you've every got your request through?

Answer (score 3):

This same thing happened to me. I ended up messaging Facebook App Review Support. In my case, I did not add the permission to the request list when the user logged in with their Facebook account, plus what I was trying to achieve with my test users just plain didn't work when the reviewer tested it (most likely because of not including it in the request list inside of the Facebook login pop up window).

I would suggest using the Facebook App Review Support chat widget. They are a huge help!

Answer (score -1):

Please have a discussion with Facebook App Review Support, they can explain the issue in the app.

You can find the messenger button to contact them in the bottom right part of the screen App Review > Requests, then click on view details and you'll be redirected to a page with a whole lot of explanation of the rejection. There you can see a messenger button in the bottom right corner, click and proceed.